# How can sub-classing affects all instance of original object?

Tags: java, object, runtime, decorator, compile-time

I was trying to learn decorator pattern from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_Pattern) it states `The decorator pattern is an alternative to subclassing. Subclassing adds behavior at compile time, and the change affects all instances of the original class; decorating can provide new behavior at run-time for individual objects.`

I have this doubt, if i create one class Original original=new Original(); then how come subclassing it as SubClass extends Original will affect the original reference of the object of class Original, it should remain intact?

Comment: it only means that any instance of the *subclass* gets its behaviour updated wrt the original class, whereas the decorator pattern let you add behaviour to a specific instance of the original class at runtime. The wording is misleading.

Comment: Personally I think that that statement in Wikipedia is incorrect. Obviously, whatever you do, the original class is not altered.